# Opening/viewing iCal in Windows

Tags: ical

I have this one condition:

The boss is using mac, the secretary is using PC. The boss keep all the schedules in iCal,  and now the secretary cannot manage and see the schedules because i dont know how to open or view iCal in Windows.

Is there any third party software that can do this?

Comment: Does he use a syncing service like Google or iCloud? Or are the calendars only available locally?

Comment: No, thats the problem, why? If the boss is using iCloud is that can help?

Comment: Well, if he chooses to sync his calendars to iCloud or Google, he can give others access to his calendars online.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Moo Calendar](http://www.moocalendar.com), it supports iCalendar format. If you have a Google Calendar account, you can use it to sync calendar with Google Calendar.